# Redirect to current page using JavaScript or servlet

Tags: servlets

I fetched students serial no from my table student and want to show all the data of a particular student by a  click on the serial no in the same page only...I want this in JavaScript or in servlet.... please help me..
                         Thank you...

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution is trying with `ajax`. It could be easy if use jQuery ajax. [Here is a link](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_ajax.asp)
Thanks.

Comment: I am unable to solve it...I don't know JQuery...I want to fetch the data from database..